# Kinesis -> Lambda -> DynamoDBでの処理遅延

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

初めて質問させていただきます。

AWSにて、KinesisにPutしたデータを
LambdaでDynamoDBへ書き込む処理を開発しています。

DynamoDBの書き込みキャパシティーユニットは十分足りているのに、
処理速度がKinesisへのデータPutの速度に追いつかず
処理の反映待ち時間がだんだん長くなってしまいました。

Kinesisのデータはシーケンシャルなので当たり前といえば当たり前なのかもしれませんが、
Lambdaが同時に１つしか動いていないようで
これをメッセージキューとワーカーが１対ｎにできれば解決できそうなのですが
Kinesis -> LambdaでKinesisシャードを増やさずにそれをする方法が見つからず、、、
そもそもKinesisの使い方が間違っている等何かアドバイスを頂きたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

【稼働情報】
Kinesisのシャード数：1
KinesisへのデータPut：秒間10〜50件

Comment: promise and batchWrite

Answer (score 2):

Lambdaで受け取った複数のデータを並列でDynamoに書き込むことで解決できました。

<sub>-- この回答は、元々質問に自己回答の形で追記されていた回答を、コミュニティ wiki として切り出したものです。</sub>